# switching platform from android to webGL in unity giving 'error building player because scripts have compile errors in the editor'

Tags: unity-game-engine

switching platform from android to webGL in unity giving error:

> 'building player because scripts have compile errors in the editor'

But not getting the details of error. I am double clicking on error but no script is opening.Using unity 5.6.0f3 version.
How can i get the log file or error details to solve it.

Comment: There should be about 2 to 3 errors when there is problem while building for WebGL. Look in the Console tab. One of them actually explains the error

Comment: You can look in the editor log file if you like. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html It sometimes has more information, but the console should also have enough information to narrow down the problem. Since you haven't said what the errors are it's hard to guess.

Comment: there is only one error that is "building player because scripts have compile errors in the editor" and only this showing nothing else in the console